# Access member variables based on ENUM (no runtime decision)

Tags: c++

My goal is to speed up my code by removing the runtime decision making of if-statements. Here's a simple example:

```
enum E
{
    E_A,
    E_B
};

class Example:
{
public:
    void DoSomething(E var) 
    {
        if (var == E_A) {
            // Do stuff with a
        } else if (var == E_B) {
            // Do stuff with b
        }
    }

private:
    set<int> a;
    set<int> b;
}
```

I've split the above `DoSomething()` function into 2.

```
void DoSomething(E::E_A var) {
    // Do stuff with a
}

void DoSomething(E::E_B var) {
    // Do stuff with b
}
```

The problem is I have to rewrite the same code twice... We could use an inbetween function:

```
void DoSomething(E_A var) {
    InBetween(a);
}

void DoSomething(E_B var) {
    InBetween(b);
}

void InBetween(set<int> s) 
{
    // Do something with s
}

set<int> a;
set<int> b;
```

However I was wondering if there's a way to achieve what I want with just a single DoSomething()? I want the code to have minimal runtime so please avoid solutions like storing storing a and b inside a map and looking up based on key.

Or please suggest me some areas to look into. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The proper answer is: have you measured the impact of having a branch? This is most likely premature optimization.

Comment: And is there really a branch in the resulting code? If the compiler can inline `DoSomething(E_A)` it will surely notice that the condition is constant and optimize it away.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `DoSomething` template (and `var` template parameter). Then you can apply [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17), which performs dispatch at compile-time. E.g.

```
template <E var>
void DoSomething() 
{
    if constexpr (var == E_A) {
        // Do stuff with a
    } else if constexpr (var == E_B) {
        // Do stuff with b
    }
}
```

Then call it as

```
a_Example.DoSomething<E::E_A>();
a_Example.DoSomething<E::E_B>();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. To follow on, would this offload the if condition burden up the line (where we need to determine which a_Example.DoSomething<E> we should call)? since we cannot pass variables into a template

Comment: @Jamesyyy Yes the template argument like `E::E_A` or `E::E_B` must be specified in the `<>` (at compile-time).